# Admin: Link fields attribute to checkbox value using linking properties of UI components

Tags: magento2, admin, uicomponent

How to use linking properties of UI components to trigger 'disabled' on input based on checkbox 'value'?

From [documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/ui_comp_guide/concepts/ui_comp_linking_concept.html), there are few ways to use `export` / `import` / `links` / `listens` to trigger disabled value of one input based on the value of another. I've tried few combinations but only thing I achieved is disabling field. How do I link  `monday_status` value to trigger `monday_open` disabled flag?

XML:

```
<field name="monday_status">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            ...
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">monday_status</item>
            <item name="default" xsi:type="number">1</item>
            <item name="links" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="disabled" xsi:type="string">value</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
<field name="monday_open">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            ...
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">monday_open</item>
            <item name="links" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="disabled" xsi:type="string">disabled</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

I've removed redundant code.

Answer (score 0):

If the `monday_status` is the checkbox, you could link its check status to `monday_open` enable/disable status with this code:

```
    <field name="monday_status">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
<item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">checkbox</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">monday_status</item>
                <item name="default" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                <!-- here the correct linking property -->
                <item name="exports" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="checked" xsi:type="string">${$.parentName}.monday_open:disabled</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
<field name="monday_open">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            ...
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">monday_open</item>
            <!-- remove your linking property from this components -->
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```